# Getting display device output type with DirectX

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I need to find out, in code (C++ on Windows 7), whether my video card is using vga, dvi or hdmi output, but from looking through the DirectX documentation I haven't found a way to do this. Using GetAdapterDisplayMode() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174316%28v=VS.85%29.aspx I can get the screen size and refresh rate and 'Format' in a D3DDISPLAYMODE structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but I'm not sure what the 'Format' represents, or whether it's relevant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Management Interface provides [some information on attached monitors.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

See here for a [C++ example on how to query the WMI.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To check the monitor connection type, use the namespace "**root\\wmi**" and query "**Select * from WmiMonitorConnectionParams**". The VideoOutputTechnology column of the result is one of [D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)